# N1QL - Insert-Select

Tags: couchbase, insert-into, sql++, insert-select

I'm trying to execute an [insert-select](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/insert.html) statement in `N1QL` (inserting documents that their key/value are the result of a select statement) and I'm failing to understand the syntax.

I tried executing:

```
insert into tempbucket (KEY payload.id,VALUE select * from default where payload.fooId in [100,101 ] )  RETURNING * ;
```

in  some variations but nothing worked.

Edit: The SELECT statement is

> select * from default where payload.fooId in [100,101 ]

The KEY of the documents I want to create is the value of the field `key`  and the VALUE is the entire JSON of the SELECT statement mentioned above.

Comment: Please edit your question and separate out the following the 3 things: the SELECT statement to be used as your source; the part of the SELECT to be used as the KEY; the part of the SELECT to be used as the VALUE. Please put each in a separate paragraph for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KEY and VALUE must reference expressions from your query.

```
INSERT INTO tempbucket (KEY d.`key`, VALUE d)
SELECT d
FROM default d
WHERE payload.fooId IN [100,101 ]
;
```